# Same object in component and yield block

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I am following the instruction on
http://ember.guru/2014/master-your-modals-in-ember-js
to create a reusable modal. I am trying to make an extensible modal that will be used for simple editing in various places around a gui.

In application.js I have

```
showModal: function(name, model) {
  this.render(name, {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'modal',
    model: model
  });
}
```

In a template I call this action from a link passing in a contact:

```
<a class="contact-edit" {{action 'showModal' 'contact-edit' contact}}>Edit contact</a>
```

contact-edit.hbs:

```
{{#my-modal objectEditing=model as |theObject|}}
  <input type="text" name="phone" value="{{theObject.phone}}">
{{/my-modal}}
```

my-modal.hbs:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  {{yield objectEditing}}
</div>
```

my-modal.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function () {
      this.$('.modal').modal('hide');
      this.sendAction('save', this.get('objectEditing'));
    },
  },
  show: function () {
    this.$('.modal').modal().on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      this.sendAction('close');
    }.bind(this));
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

The problem is edits to theObject in the line `<input type="text" name="phone" value="{{theObject.phone}}">` are not showing up in the action being called here (which is on the route). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to tell you, its a bit an old tutorial. May you should consider to checkout [ember-wormhole](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole) for a modal without outlets and just components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input, you should pass in an action that will update your value. The value won't update automatically by itself:

```
{{#my-modal objectEditing=model as |theObject|}}
  <input
    type="text"
    name="phone"
    value={{theObject.phone}}
    oninput={{action (mut theObject.phone) value="target.value"}}
  >
{{/my-modal}}
```

Note that the `value` attribute above isn't surrounded by double quotes. :)

Comment: Arghhh! Sorry for wasting your time: I forgot to use the {{input}} helper. I was sure it had something to do with the yielding and didn't see the obvious :)